# Get HH-MM-SS in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to get HH-MM-SS in Meteor as shown in the below:

```
var result = "hhmmss";
```

Date  : Wed Aug 14 2058 12:18:31 GMT+0530 (IST) // here we need only HH-MM-SS like as string as mention same as above.

I am new to meteor. So didn't het any idea about this. Please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the same thing as in plain Javascript:

```
var pad = function(n) {
  return ((n < 10) ? '0' : '') + n;
};

var result = pad(date.getHours()) + pad(date.getMinutes()) + pad(date.getSeconds());
```

Working with time is not pleasant in plain JS, so if your app handles a lot of date / time values it might be handy to include [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in the project. For example, the above snipped could be simplified with Moment to the following line:

```
var result = moment(date).format('HHmmss');
```